# How to use input-group to specify input conditionally?

Tags: bixby

I'm trying use the the user's default geo location info *unless* she specifies a different location. So, "What's happening" should pass geolocation information in her profile. "What's happening in Tulsa" passes geolocation information about Tulsa.

I'm using an input-group to do this:

```
 input-group (where) {
  requires (OneOf)
  collect {
    input (location) {
         min (Optional) max (One)
         type (viv.geo.NamedPoint)
          default-select {
             with-rule {
               select-first
            }
        }
      }
     input (myLocation) {
       min (Optional) max(One)
       type (viv.geo.GeoPoint)

       default-init {
         if ($user.currentLocation.$exists) {
           intent {
             goal: geo.GeoPoint
             value-set: geo.CurrentLocation { $expr ($user.currentLocation) }
           }
         } 
       }
     }
    }
  }
```

This works.

But I'm wondering if there a better way to do this? Is there some way to do it with a more standard conditional logic (like an if/then or unless statement in the action?

Comment: Seems you don't need input-group. default-init should be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try this using `default-init`, which provides a default input if none is provided:

```
input (myLocation) {
       min (Required) max(One)
       type (viv.geo.GeoPoint)

       default-init {
         if ($user.currentLocation.$exists) {
           intent {
             goal: geo.GeoPoint
             value-set: geo.CurrentLocation { $expr ($user.currentLocation) }
           }
         } 
       }
```

Comment: Great answer! In this case. min (Required) will force an input value, and if it is not there, default-init will use current location. This should get the job done.

Comment: Great! Thanks. I guess I don't understand how default-init works. The docs say it supplies "A default value for an input or variable type." Is the default value of $user.currentLocation being overwritten? If so, then this solution has the following (small) issue: it requires getting user consent to access their current location when that isn't necessary to fulfill the request.

Comment: The proposed answer is a great solution for what you're asking.   If the user opts-in to allow their location point to be given..you'll get the location.  Otherwise, the user will be prompted for a location. That's how the logic for default-init works in this case.